# update firestore field with special character using flutter(dart)

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firestore document which has a field name 'return/replace'. I want to update this field, but on update it throws the following error
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Use FieldPath.of() for field names containing '~*/[]'.`

I have tried the following update queries.

```
 Firestore.instance
        .collection('collection')
        .document('someDocID')
        .updateData({
           'return\/replace': 1
       });
```

Also

```
 Firestore.instance
        .collection('collection')
        .document('someDocID')
        .updateData({
           'return/replace': 1
       });
```

But both gives same error. Also according to the error I tried using FieldPath.of() but flutter has nothing like that.. If anyone could suggest a code snippet would be helpful.

Comment: Did anyone find any solution to this? I even tried FieldPath.of() but it doesn't work still... :(

Comment: yeah even i am facing same issue... i would like to know if you found any solution?

Comment: @Itachi I still didn't find any solution for it.. :/

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you to call [`FieldPath.of()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FieldPath#of(java.lang.String...)), which creates a field path that **can** refer to your field.

But from a quick look at the [FlutterFire documentation for [`FieldPath`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/latest/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/FieldPath-class.html) it seems that `of` is currently not wrapped there. This means you currently can't update/query the field from Flutter.. You might want to file a feature request, or submit a PR for adding a wrapper for `FieldPah.of`.

You might also want to give the workaround that is mentioned here a try: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/626

Comment: That workaround didn't work.. it still throws the same error...:(....Guess it's not possible in flutter then...